# Google Analytics not working with Barbajs

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, barbajs

Trying to use the latest google analytics tracking code in a site that uses Barba JS but it will not track past the first page, ie the path of the user, any ideas anybody?

Comment: are you using analytics.js, gtag.js or GTM?

Answer (score 0):

The reason it is only working on the initial page is that the default GA snippet implemented using gtag.js only runs once after load. Since you're using it in a SPA setting, you need to manually re-send the page data when you route. Looking at the barbajs documentation, I think it'll be something like this:

```
// define a global hook, using afterEnter, but you can adjust to enter, beforeEnter, etc as you see fit.
barba.hooks.afterEnter((data) => {
  // this hook will be called for each transitions
  //data.current.url is the page path.
  gtag('config', 'UA-#######-1', {'page_path': data.current.url});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use full code provide with google annalitics
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/?hl=en

in you JS add

```
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');
```